# Estimating values in large SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a project to use sampling methods to estimate large datasets, for instance, in a dataset of 1,000,000 rows, using random sampling to find a faster estimation of an AVERAGE of the rows. Would the best place to start messing with this be from a SQL query, and writing it in SQL? Or should I be looking into building an implementation directly into an SQL plugin or something? I'd like to do the actual work myself, so I'm mostly looking for a point in the right direction. Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you please share some examples and explain your expected result along with it

Comment: Please share the RDBMS you are using ..SQLServer/Oracle/Mysql..?

Comment: I'm using SQLserver. Basically it was a question posed by one of my professors in class that we could use sampling to make queries on large datasets much faster (So I guess on sets of like 100,000,000 instead of 1,000,000), but I'd like to see how to implement it myself

Comment: Standard SQL supports the `tablesample` option to pick random rows of a table. I don't know if SQL Server supports that as well

Comment: Would there be an easy way to try another sampling method, such as stratified sampling?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `tablesample` support was added in SQL Server 2005.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=sql.105).aspx. AFAIK it works by selecting random pages, not rows, so it may not be the best sample.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide RDBMS implementation, and SQL is base standard... I would share idea for PostgreSQL. Maybe that can be used for other, as well. Each table, index, has statistics. So you can reason what is average value, or how many entries are there. That is not precise, but better then random sampling.

As a side note 1M rows is not that much.